# Is there an online course in Mathematical Methods for Physics, Covering Matrices and Vector Analysis?

Tags: resource-recommendations, vectors, linear-algebra

I am taking a course in Mathematical Methods for physicsPhysics (Junior Level).   We are working from   > Mathematical Methods for physicists, George B.Arfken .    I just need online resources covering ( Matrices, Determinants, Vector Analysis, Tensors and differential forms and Vector spaces...etc) to study and understand from.

Comment: This course is probably more rigorous than you need but, https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd.

Comment: Hi Mohamed Ayman: Res. recom. questions, which often tend to become  _primarily opinion-based_ list questions, are strictly regulated on Phys.SE, cf. various meta posts. Lin. alg. penetrates every area of physics, so this question seems also _too broad._ I close it as a _duplicate,_ not because it is an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I only know of these:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYNOGk3ZjFM (PERIMETER INSTITUTE RECORDED SEMINAR ARCHIVE)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5VUnapu-qs&list=PLiUVvsKxTUr66oLF6Pzirc1EgSstMbRZR (Indian University of Technology Madras)
The first two I recommend because they are simply the same courses as the one that you are attending.

The following are pure mathematics but I know that their quality of teaching is very good and also cover most of the material that you described.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw6pHhjhKmk&list=PLRjmB-sfc2DjB3bJjoTwo0FRyyes9xTay&index=1 (UC Berkeley)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK3O402wf1c&list=PLRjmB-sfc2DjB3bJjoTwo0FRyyes9xTay&index=2 (MIT by Gilbert Strang who is considered by many to many a very good teacher)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxCxlsl_YwY&list=PLRjmB-sfc2DjB3bJjoTwo0FRyyes9xTay&index=3 (MIT- this is my personal favorite!)

Comment: Thank you , but from the videos names, I don't see that they cover the topics covered by Arfken, Is this the case? or they are just the same thing with different names?!

Comment: They are the only lectures on mathematical physics(the same with your course). Do you mind watching lectures that are intended for mathematicians?

Comment: I will edit with a few more lecture that MIGHT help although I am not sure. There are vectors and matrices for sure but I don't know if they cover everything that you will cover in your course.

Comment: This does not conform to the standard for answers to resource recommendation questions as laid out in [our policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4698/50583). Please add short descriptions of what the links contain and *why* you recommend them.

Comment: Yes, they are very useful. Although, they are the same concepts, they don't cover the same level of depth that Arfken do. But, it's always useful to get a deeper understanding of preliminary concepts. Thanks alot.